# Android How to check Version

Tags: android

I did my application in 2.2 environment, when i install my apk in older version i am getting parser error. is there anything possibility to display our own message instead parser error message. As per my opinion it is not.

Comment: Where and when do you get this parser error?

Comment: At the time when installing the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this

```
private int GetVersion()
{
    int version = 0;
    IPackageManager pm = ActivityThread.getPackageManager();
    try
    {
        //returns a ref to my application according to its application name
        ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo("com.android.phonetests", 0);

        if (applicationInfo != null) 
        {           
            version = applicationInfo.targetSdkVersion; 

            //2 is 5
            //2.01 6 (Donut - 2.01)
            //2.2  7 (Eclair - 2.2) currently it is Eclair_MR1 (Major Release)                  
            switch (version) 
            {                           
                case Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR_MR1:
                Log.i(LOG_TAG,"[DBG] version: ECLAIR");//2.2  7 (Eclair - 2.2) currently it is Eclair_MR1 (Major Release)
                break;
                case Build.VERSION_CODES.DONUT:
                Log.i(LOG_TAG,"[DBG] version: DONUT");//2.01 6 (Donut - 2.01)
                break;
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (android.os.RemoteException e){}      
    return version;
}
```

Comment: Actually, Eclair is 2.1 (API level 7) and Froyo is 2.2 (API level 8)

Comment: Thanks for immediate replies. I have a doubt, can you explain about what you written in switch case. what Log should do,is that displaying error message or something other than this..??

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you build for version 2.2 and then you deploy it on an earlier version. Why don't you build it for that earlier version?

I don't think you can get another error than that parse error.

Comment: Your idea is good, but what i am asking is in case if i install my apk in older version instead of 2.2, before installing the file i want to display the message like "sorry you need 2.2". is this possible to do in application perspective..??