# Layout orientation?

Tags: java, android

I made 2 layout , the first one for android 2.1 ( I need it only in `portrait`) and second one for android 3 ( I need it only in `landscape`) and these 2 layout use one class . now how can i set these two layout on landscape and portrait? if i set it in `AndroidManifest` , i can just use one of these mode `portrait` or `landscape` , just it ,

we can't use:

```
<activity android:name=".activity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
```

now which method is true?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its rely not necessary to set screen Orientation attribute.

i am also handle this senario in my project.
you make two folder in resours

first for portraitemode
and second for landscape maode

like  layout folder  and layout-land folder

layout---store all layout when u wann give in portraitr mode
layout-land----store all layout when u wann give in landscape mode

Answer (score 0):

It's just not necessary to set `screenOrientation` attribute, remove it and you'll be fine.

Comment: yup that's right but in android 2.1 i need it only in portrait and in android 3 i need it only in landscape!!!

Comment: You can choose what layout to set as content view in code, depending on what version of OS device is using. Check this link to know how to check device's version:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919267/android-how-to-check-version