# How to check android sdk version in Ubuntu through terminal?

Tags: android, ubuntu

I have installed android sdk in my Ubuntu machine, i am trying to see what is the version i am using.
When Googled i found few links for this in stack overflow

[How to retrieve the android sdk version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882883/how-to-retrieve-the-android-sdk-version)

[Android How to check Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919267/android-how-to-check-version)

These links specify method to get version via code, but how do i check it through terminal in ubuntu?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two methods you posted are applicable for Android devices not for a computer that has Android SDKs installed to develop. You should have many Android SDKs installed on your Ubuntu machine.

The check in the terminal all the SDKs in your machine you can use [sdkmanager](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html) tool:

```
${ANDROID_HOME}/tools/bin/sdkmanager --list
```

It will show you three main blocks: `Installed packages`, `Available Packages` and `Available Updates`.

You can use the same tool to update and install/uninstall packages too.

Comment: Hey! It would be helpful if you add the method to check sdk version from terminal since it is the first link that Google throws off.

Comment: `${ANDROID_HOME}` is the folder where you have installed Android SDK. Typically is `~/android-sdks`.

Comment: echo $ANDROID_HOME will give you the value , Typically it will be /home/<username>/Android/Sdk